# How can I verify that a DbContext is not tracking and is using split queries

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-core

I have set one of my `DbContext`'s to use split queries as:

```cs
builder.Services.AddDbContextFactory<NoTrackingDbContext>(options =>
    options.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("LouisHoweDb"),
        x =>
        {
            x.UseNetTopologySuite();
            x.UseQuerySplittingBehavior(QuerySplittingBehavior.SplitQuery);
        })
);
```

And to do no tracking with:

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    base.OnConfiguring(optionsBuilder);
    optionsBuilder.UseQueryTrackingBehavior(QueryTrackingBehavior.NoTracking);
}
```

And both appear to be working, looking at the raw queries and the attached Entities (none). Is that the best way to verify? Or is there a way to look at `DbContext` properties to verify?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the following code snippets:

```cs
var options = context.GetService<IDbContextOptions>();

var coreOptions = options.FindExtension<CoreOptionsExtension>();
if (coreOptions != null)
{
    var queryTrackingBehavior = coreOptions.QueryTrackingBehavior;
}

var relational = options.Extensions.OfType<RelationalOptionsExtension>().FirstOrDefault();
if (relational != null)
{
    var querySplittingBehavior = relational.QuerySplittingBehavior;
}
```

Comment: Is there a way to verify if tracking is on/off through this also? TIA

Comment: `QueryTrackingBehavior` is not enough?

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't realize what `queryTrackingBehaviour` was. I thought is was also for the SplitQuery behavior. Yes, that is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to verify split queries is with a profiler. Have it capturing the SQL being run against a test database, preferably something that isn't getting a lot of traffic from other systems. When you execute a query /w `AsSplitQuery` you should see several individual SQL statements being run instead of one query with a number of `JOIN`s. Somewhat similar to what happens with lazy loading but it should be one query per entity/table. (vs. one query per table per top-level row /w lazy loading which can be an expensive scenario)

For verifying whether or not tracking is happening, the easiest way is to add a temporary check after a query. If you are loading records from TableA with joins to TableB, after the query you can inspect the DbSet.Local to see if there are any tracking instances:

```
var results = context.TableAs.Include(a => a.TableBs).Where(a => /* condition */).ToList();
bool hasTrackedInstances = context.TableAs.Local.Any() || context.TableBs.Local.Any();
```

If the query is running without tracking enabled then the `.Local` tracking caches should remain empty.